# Numpy Array: Efficiently find matching indices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two lists, one of which is massive (millions of elements), the other several thousand. I want to do the following

```
bigArray=[0,1,0,2,3,2,,.....]

smallArray=[0,1,2,3,4]

for i in len(smallArray):
  pts=np.where(bigArray==smallArray[i])
  #Do stuff with pts...
```

The above works, but is slow.  Is there any way to do this more efficiently without resorting to writing something in C?

Comment: I really doubt you would get much speedup when ported to C since most likely the comparison operation and the `where` operation are already implemented in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case you may benefit from presorting your big array. Here is the example demonstrating how you can reduce the time from ~ 45 seconds to 2 seconds (on my laptop)(for one particular set of lengths of the arrays 5e6 vs 1e3). Obviously the solution won't be optimal if the array sizes will be wastly different. E.g. with the default solution the complexity is O(bigN*smallN), but for my suggested solution it is O((bigN+smallN)*log(bigN))

```
import numpy as np, numpy.random as nprand, time, bisect

bigN = 5e6
smallN = 1000
maxn = 1e7
nprand.seed(1)  
bigArr = nprand.randint(0, maxn, size=bigN)
smallArr = nprand.randint(0, maxn, size=smallN)

# brute force 
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(len(smallArr)):
    inds = np.where(bigArr == smallArr[i])[0]
t2 = time.time()
print "Brute", t2-t1

# not brute force (like nested loop with index scan)
t1 = time.time()
sortedind = np.argsort(bigArr)
sortedbigArr = bigArr[sortedind]
for i in range(len(smallArr)):
    i1 = bisect.bisect_left(sortedbigArr, smallArr[i])
    i2 = bisect.bisect_right(sortedbigArr, smallArr[i])
    inds = sortedind[i1:i2]
t2=time.time()
print "Non-brute", t2-t1
```

Output:

Brute 42.5278530121

Non-brute 1.57193303108

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but there is probably room for optimization by using `np.searchsorted` instead of the loop with the bisection.

Answer (score 11):

Numpy provides the function numpy.searchsorted: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sorted = np.argsort(big_list)
>>> r = np.searchsorted(big_list, small_list, side='right',sorter=sorted)
>>> l  = np.searchsorted(big_list, small_list, side='left',sorter=sorted)
>>> for b, e in zip(l, r):
...     inds = sorted[b:e]
```

Comment: I didn't test the bisection version, but in my quick experiment this is at least faster than the `defaultdic` lookup answer. In my setup by a bit more than a factor of 2.

Answer (score 3):

So far I don't see any need for numpy; you can make use of `defaultdict`, provided that you memory is sufficient, it should be if number of observation is not too many millions.

```
big_list = [0,1,0,2,3,2,5,6,7,5,6,4,5,3,4,3,5,6,5]
small_list = [0,1,2,3,4]

from collections import defaultdict

dicto = defaultdict(list) #dictionary stores all the relevant coordinates
                          #so you don't have to search for them later

for ind, ele in enumerate(big_list):
    dicto[ele].append(ind)
```

Result:

```
>>> for ele in small_list:
...     print dicto[ele]
... 
[0, 2]
[1]
[3, 5]
[4, 13, 15]
[11, 14]
```

This should give you some speed.