# Remove segments from numpy array that have a total intensity below a certain threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm working on a segmentation script that filters segments based on segment size (area) and the total intensity of pixels within each segment.

I figured out how to remove segments based on area by following the answer in this post:

[Returning specific numpy label indices for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585481/returning-specific-numpy-label-indices-for-an-image)

In the final part of the script I'd like to remove segments that have a total intensity below a certain threshold.

Hopefully this example shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
A = np.array([

      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
      [0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 4, 9, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0],
      [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])
```

I can get the sum of each segment using:

```
label_A, nb_labels = ndimage.label(A)
seg_sum = ndimage.sum(A, label_A, range(nb_labels + 1))
seg_sum

Output: array([ 0.,  4., 20.,  7., 27., 12.,  3.])`
```

I'd like to be able to convert any segments that have a sum less than 10 to zeros. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from `seg_sum`, you could check which components sum less than `10` and use `np.in1d` to check which values to set to zero in `A`:

```
labels_to_zero = np.arange(1,len(seg_sum))[seg_sum[1:]>=10]
# array([2, 4, 5])

ix = np.in1d(label_A, labels_to_zero)

np.where(ix, A.ravel(), 0).reshape(A.shape)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 9, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks!
I think this will work. 

For some reason when perform the seg_sum command on the actual segments on the images I want to analyze, it orders the sums in the resulting output array from small to large. I don't get this behaviour with the example I posted. I'm unsure why this happens.

Then if I contiune on with your suggestion on the real segments, it deletes the top 3rd of segments no matter what sum they have. 

Any ideas? Could the ordering discrepancy be the root of the problem?

Comment: Hmm not sure why that could be. I can't see any reference to this behaviour in the docs.. Perhaps post another example where it fails? Though I'd be surprised, it doesn't seem too logical @Landy