# How to perform a vectorised check if each word in an array appears in an array of sentences?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 1D array of words. For each word, I need to grab each sentence for which it appears in, where the sentences are defined in a separate 1D array.

Simple working example with a for-loop:

```
import numpy as np

sentences = np.array(['This is an apple tree', 'The cat is sleeping'])
words = np.array(['apple', 'dog', 'cat'])
matches = []

for word in words:
    for sentence in sentences:
        if word in sentence:
            matches.append([word, sentence])

print(matches)
```

**How can I vectorise this operation?** I tried using `np.where` and `np.select` but it doesn't seem to let me make the `in` comparison.

```
# select example
conditions = [words in sentences]
choices = [words]
print(np.select(conditions, choices))

# where example
print(np.where(words in sentences))
```

Both yielding:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Perhaps I need to somehow employ `np.all` or `np.any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be interpreted two different ways, with slightly different solutions. Do you want to find substrings? Or do you want to find matches exactly at word boundaries?

#### Finding Substrings

[`numpy.char`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html) provides some vectorized string-matching functions:

```
>>> np.char.find(sentences[None,:], words[:,None])
array([[11, -1],
       [-1, -1],
       [-1,  4]])
```

Like Python's own `find` function, this returns `-1` when the substring is not found, and the index of the substring otherwise. The `[None,:]` and `[:,None]` selectors simply reshape the arrays to be broadcastable.

This is diving pretty deep into `numpy` esoterica, so YMMV. The docs report this about the functions in `numpy.char`:

> All of them are based on the string methods in the Python standard library.

If that means it's calling Python functions internally, then it will not be very fast, but the vectorization will still provide some speedup.

To fully answer your question, you can now call `np.where` and `np.c_` on the output like so:

```
>>> r, c = np.where(np.char.find(sentences[None,:], words[:,None]) != -1)
>>> matches = np.c_[words[r], sentences[c]]
>>> matches
array([['apple', 'This is an apple tree'],
       ['cat', 'The cat is sleeping']], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

(Thanks to [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) for the last suggestion.)

#### Finding Exact Word Matches

If your aim is to match exact words rather than substrings, then you might be better off splitting the sentences into arrays of words. In Natural Language Processing lingo, that's called *tokenization*. Then the problem is that the sentences will be of different lengths, and so won't fit into a fixed-size array as nicely. Here's one way to deal with that problem. First, generate an array of words (*tokens*) and an array of sentence *labels*:

```
>>> s_words = np.array([w for s in sentences for w in s.split()])
>>> s_labels = np.array([i for i, s in enumerate(sentences) for w in s.split()])
```

Then check if they are equal in a broadcasted way:

```
>>> r, c = (s_words[:,None] == words).nonzero()
```

And proceed as above, but using the sentence labels as indices into the original sentences array:

```
>>> #               _________< -- another layer of indirection
>>> np.c_[words[c], sentences[s_labels[r]]]
array([['apple', 'This is an apple tree'],
       ['cat', 'The cat is sleeping']], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

This will still be slow for very long lists of words combined with many sentences, although it will be faster than the `find` method above. There are some tricks for speeding a search like this up using [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), but they require some additional logic to ensure that all matches are found. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10320751/577088) provide some guidance along those lines.

Finally, note that this simply uses the Python `split()` method to "tokenize" the sentences. If you want *real* tokenization, you could use a tokenizer from a package like [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/) or [`spacy`](https://spacy.io/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to set me straight. Serves me right for trying to answer away from a console just by looking at the docs. Learning experience at least.

Comment: @RickTeachey no worries! I'm sure there's a pure python solution along the lines you were describing, and it might not be slower than `numpy` in this case. Might be worth testing (hint, hint).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mind explaining why we need to broadcast the arrays?

Comment: Well, "need" isn't quite the right word. Let me put it this way: if vectorization eliminates one loop; broadcasting eliminates two (or more) nested loops. Your pure Python code has a nested pair of loops over words and sentences, right? It checks each `(word, sentence)` pair to see if the sentence contains the word. That's what broadcasting does too. Slicing with `None` adds a new (length 1) dimension, so `sentences` becomes a row vector, and `words` becomes a column vector. `numpy` "imagines" a table, with a different `(sentence, word)` pair at every cell. Then it maps `find` over the table.

Comment: Cool, I think I understand now - we had to reshape the arrays in order to allow for element-wise operations. And from I have tested, we can achieve the same effect by using `.reshape`. I can see the advantage of slicing them with `None` to achieve the same result - you do not need to know the number of elements - is this common practice over using `.reshape`?

Comment: @Petar, yes, exactly! It's a pretty common practice, and there's even an alias, `numpy.newaxis` that just contains `None`. This has always bugged me: `None` is a little confusing here; `numpy.newaxis` is unnecessarily verbose. Grr.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! However I just realised - the `find` method doesn't return exact matches, so the word `'is'` will get "found" in `'this ...'` for example. I will need to figure something out...

Comment: @Petar I added one possible solution for exact word matching. It's not asymptotically optimal but there are a couple of links for possible solutions to that problem as well.

Comment: Thanks @senderle :)